# Load image based on folder and ignore further text after trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder structure like

```
root/images/folder1
```

In folder1 is exactly 1 image for example `test.jpg`

Now I would like to show the image test.jpg only by calling the URL

```
www.example.com/images/folder1
```

Is it possible to define mod_rewrite in a way to only match the folder name and therefore load the image inside.

In case the user would call

```
www.example.com/images/folder1/somethingelse
```

I would still like to call the image taking only into account what is between the two "/" after `www.example.com/images`

Comment: `/images/folder1` - do you specifically want to avoid the trailing slash? "exactly 1 image f.e test.jpg" - what is "f.e"?

Comment: I don't have to avoid the trailing slash. I would be also happy with www.domain.com/images/folder1/
(f.e.  - for example)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a single internal rewrite that matches exactly that path prefix:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?images/folder1 /images/folder1/test.jpg [END]
```

UPDATE:

In the first comment to this question you now additionally ask whether it is possible to implement a more generic rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?images/([^/]+) /images/$1/test.jpg [END]
```

Comment: Can this also be rewritten in an overall logic avoiding single rewrite rules. The "folder1" in the url is always pointing to the correct folder on the server. Per folder I only have one image.

Comment: Sure that is possible, I added an update to the question.

Comment: Thank you. Let me test it today. One more question. In case I do not know the file name of the jpg file. Is there also a rule that would be referencing to the file based on the folder? As said I only have one image per folder but it does not have to be names test.jpg It could have any other name too.

Comment: I do not see an immediate way to implement such a rule. It certainly is possible to implement such thing based on a router script, so that you hand over all such requests to a simple php script which checks the folder, finds the image and forwards that image to the client. But the more obvious solution would be to simply rename those files so that they have a common name, that should be possible with a one liner command ...

Comment: Well, actually this _would_ be possible on protocol level if the file names cannot be arbitrary, but if you can name a reasonable small set of possible names. In that case you could simply use the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have to avoid the trailing slash. I would be also happy with `www.example.com/images/folder1/`

In that case, you would just use the `DirectoryIndex` directive, either in the specific folder to apply to just that folder or in the parent folder (ie. `/images`) to apply to all subfolders.

The `DirectoryIndex` directive instructs Apache/mod_dir which file to serve when requesting the directory. Normally, this is set to `index.html` (default) or `index.php` etc. But it can be set to anything.

For example:

```
# /images/.images
DirectoryIndex test.jpg
```

The above would tell mod_dir to try and serve `test.jpg` from any (sub)directory when requesting the directory itself.

For example, requesting `/images/folder1/` would serve `/images/folder1/test.jpg` if it exists, otherwise a 403 Forbidden is served (assuming mod_autoindex is enabled, but directory listings are disabled).

If you omit the trailing slash on the directory then mod_dir will first trigger a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash (in order to "fix" the URL).

This of course assumes you are always serving `test.jpg` from whatever directory is requested.

---

> In case the user would call
>
> ```
> www.example.com/images/folder1/somethingelse
> ```
>
> I would still like to call the image taking only into account what is between the two "/" after `www.example.com/images`

This would potentially cause a duplicate content issue and have a negative effect on SEO. Not to mention opening your site up to abuse, eg. `/image/folder1/malicious-keywords-here`.

With the `DirectoryIndex` method discussed above then `/images/folder1/somethingelse` would naturally result in 404 (unless a file by that name existed).

If you wanted `/images/folder1/somethingelse` to serve `/images/folder1/` then you should implement an external 301 redirect to the canonical URL.

Comment: My page is held in different languages. Due to SEO I would like to provide the images in different languages. At the moment my solution is to either provide the images multiple times to serve different names per language or to have a solution as described as above. I see your point with abusive keywords nevertheless the workflow for me would be easier to create images only once for all languages and find a solution which would allow calling them using different expressions. This is the reason why I am looking for a possibility to call the images named /folder1/language_expression.jpg